# WPF DataGrid disabled row Foreground color not beeing set

Tags: c#, wpf

I face a problem with WPF DataGrid.

I want to set the `Foreground` value of a disabled `DataGrid` row, but the `Foreground` stays always gray.

Here is the code I use:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridRowDoubleClick" />
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=IsMD4Valid}" />
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="{Binding Path=IsMD4Valid}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Added">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Changed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Deleted">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="false" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkRed"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

`Added`, `Changed` and `Deleted` are just enum values.

Here is what I get:

[image: wrong Foreground color for rows with red Background]

As you can see, the `Background` is applied, but the `Foreground` not (for row with `Deleted` State)

Comment: I think is getting the style of IsEnable, you can try:

`<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Trigger>`

Comment: @Nekeniehl that didn't work, added the trigger under `Style.Triggers`

Comment: Hmm, strange, I have similar code and is working with the `IsSelected`, it should work with the `IsEnabled`. Try on `DataGridCell` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a custom `DataGridCell` style:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: Ok, that worked, have you an idea why it doesn't work with row style?

Comment: Because the default CellStyle sets the Foreground of disabled cell contents. By defining a custom cell style you are "overriding" this behaviour.

Comment: And the why did the row style override the cell style in other cases successfully and in the case that the row is disable not?

Comment: Because there is an IsEnabled trigger defined in the default cell style that sets the Foreground to SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey.